# Command not found on a funciton calling from another

Tags: linux, bash, function, rpm, getopts

i've tried to figure our , what wrong with my script , i tried using the below syntax for function
fucntion name{ } , and also example(){} , both results creates errors , please advise what's wrong with my script

```
# Objective : automation script for createing rpm package

usage(){

  echo "in order to use this script you need to add the filename which"
  echo "contain the script. for Example"
  echo "s scriptname.sh"
  break
}

 check(){

   # check if package exists , if not install it.
   chk1=$(yum list installed | grep rpmdevtools) 
   chk2=$(yum list installed | grep rpmbuild)
   chk3=$(yum list installed | grep rpmdev)
   if [[ ! -z ${chk1} ]] && [[ ! -z ${chk2} ]] && [[ ! -z ${chk3} ]];then 
     echo "package doesn't exist, installing packages" 
     sleep 5 
     sudo yum install wget -y
     wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpmdevtools-8.3-5.el7.noarch.rpm
     sudo yum install rpmdevtools-8.3-5.el7.noarch.rpm -y
     rpmcreate
   else
     echo "package exists .."
     sleep 5
     rpmcreate
  fi
 }


rpmcreate()
 {
 # creating rpmtree
 cd $HOME
 rpmdev-setuptree
 starti
 }


 while getopts s:h arg; do 

 case "$arg" in 
  h)
    usage 
    ;;
  s)myarg=${OPTARG}
    check
    ;;
  :)usage
    ;;
  \?)usage
    ;;
  esac
done

# creating script file
starti(){

# move the script to SOURCE
mydir=$(echo $myarg | awk -F'.' '{print $1}') 
mkdir $mydir-0.0.1
mv $myydir.sh $mydir-0.0.1
tar --create --file $mydir-0.0.1.tar.gz $mydir-0.0.1
sudo mv $mydir-0.0.1.tar.gz ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES

# create a spec file
rpmdev-newspec $mydir

# move the file to SPECS Folder

mv ./$mydir.spec ~/rpmbuild/SPECS

cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS

   sed '2d','4d','7,8d','20,22d','25,27d','31d' $mydir.spec
   sed 's/Version:/0.0.1/;s/Summary:/Summary:Sample/;s/License:/License:GPL/;s/Source0:
   /Source0:%   {name}-%{version}.tar.gz/;s/BuildArch:/BuildArch:noarch/;s/Requires:
   /Requires:bash/;s/%description/%description\nSample\;
   s/rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/rm -rf  ${buildroot}\nmkdir -p %{buildroot}/tmp\ncp %{name}.sh
   %{buildroot}/tmp/;s/%files/%files\n/tmp/%{name}.sh/;s/%changelog/'

   # checking the spec file on error 
   check=$(rpmlint ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/$mydir.spec | awk '/checked/ {print $7}')
   if [ "$check" = "0" ];then
     echo "you did a good work lad!"
   else
     echo $check
     echo "problem with your SPECS file fix it F.I.A.T !!! (Fix it again $USER)"
fi

rpmbuild -bs ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/$mydir.spec
}
```

this is where it fails: .**/rpmrevised.sh: line 41: starti: command not found**
i'm really tring to figure this out , but with no luck

Comment: You call `check` before you define `starti`.  Move the `while` loop to the end.  Bash like most interpreted languages is interpreted line by line.  `starti` has to be defined before you can call it.

Comment: BTW, this script has quite a lot of bugs that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch.

Comment: you rule man! , thanks!!!